# RenderPartial from Modules for index.php

Tags: yii

I'm trying to call a view in my `modules/moduleName/views/ab/_temp` from my index.php file. but cant seem to get it to work.

in my side controller i have this

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new Ab;

        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$model
        ));
    }
```

in my `views/site/index.php`

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('//modulesName/views/ab/_temp', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

i'm getting this error

```
 include(Ab.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure you have a Model class file as `Ab.php` in models folder.

Comment: Are you sure the Ab.php file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller is not inside the module you should import the path to your main.php file:

```
'import'=>array(
    ...,
    'application.modules.moduleName.*',
    'application.modules.moduleName.models.*',
),
```

Comment: thanks. incase this helps someone. i had to change the location to this too `<?php $this->renderPartial('application.modules.modulesName.views.ab._temp', array('model'=>$model)); ?>`